# How to iterate over an object with dom selectors as values in an object and then use them to set value?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have a function that takes an object returned from a database as argument. I want to display the object's values in the form. I have created a key-value pair for each DOM selector for which I want to set the value. Here is the relevant code:

```js
function paintForm(item) {
    let form = {
        id: '',
        name: document.getElementById('name'),
        category: document.getElementById('category'),
        subcategory: document.getElementById('subcategory'),
        price: document.getElementById('price'),
        quantity: document.getElementById('quantity'),
        stock: document.getElementById('stock'),
        operation: document.getElementById('operation'),
        amount: document.getElementById('amount'),
        log: document.getElementById('log')
    }

    Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
        let formItem = form[key]
        formItem.setAttribute('value', item[key].toString())
    })
}
```

**The Passed Parameter for the function (item)**

```js
{
    id: 'asdiu12189ascjo',
    name: 'Nano',
    category: 'Microcontrollers',
    subcategory: 'Arduino',
    price: 250,
    quantity: 20,
    log: ['a', 'b', 'c', 's']
},
```

Here is what I tried:

**Inner HTML**

```
Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
    form[key].innerHTML = item[key].toString()
})
```

**Value**

```
Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
    form[key].value = item[key].toString()
})
```

---

**What I understand**

Using `Object[key]` gets me the value of the object to its corresponding key. Now, I am not sure if the value has to be typed. I think the value has to be stored as a string and then parsed? But I posted this since I think there are better ways to handle form values.

I am not too experienced with JS and I'm just attempting to switch from frameworks to plain js. So, kindly do not refer me to libraries or frameworks. Any help is appreciated and thank you all in advance for the contributions. :)

Comment: What does `item` looks like & why are you doing `form[item]`. Shouldn't it be `form[key]`.

Comment: What is the structure of the `item` parameter you are  passing to `paintForm()`? Also, a look at your HTML form would be nice.

Comment: @ambianBeing Yes, that was a typo. I was trying form[key] but then typed it wrong on stack since it is other things I tried. I fixed it tho.

Comment: @UdoE. I have added that as an example for your reference. The html is plain inputs with ids as mentioned in the form object.

Comment: @ParthAgarwal, the answer to your question is in the question already. The code you mentioned as **relevant code** achieves your requirements. And no, the values don't have to be typed - you already used the `toString()` method to convert all of them to string. Except you need better formatting for the last entry in `item` that is an array. Also all your inputs or at least most of them shouldn't have an `innerHTML` attribute. You should be referring to `value` attribute instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed rightly by Udo E. in comments, if all of them are `input fields` `value` attribute is the way to go: Adding a validation on `formItem` as for `undefined` returns if at all.

```
Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
          let formItem = form[key];
          if (formItem) {
            formItem.value = item[key].toString();
          }
        });
```

> if one `formItem` returns `undefined`, then the entire loop is a waste? absolutely no. The `if` clause is just an extra check for some element that wasn't found in in `DOM` via `document.getElementById` in `form` object. So if will prevent you from assigning a `value` to something `formItem.value` that wasn't found. To think of it in your case since input fields and the form object itself is predefined and `formItem` will always be found w.r.t `id`. The `if` clause might not be necessary.

Comment: So it works indeed. Could you please explain the role of handling the undefined? It seems confusing. Is it that if one `formItem` returns `undefined`, then the entire loop is a waste? I am not able to actually understand the logic behind why this works. But it does.

Comment: @ParthAgarwal Tried to explain that in the answer itself. hope that helps.

Comment: Alright. Because I tried it without the if. It did not work.

Comment: Okay! so without `if` it can fail for couple of reasons. 1) If a field like `something` is there in `item` but not in `form` object, you can guess this would fail `form[key];` 2) If a field like `something` is there in `item`& in `form` object as well, but no element in DOM has that as `id` prop this will fail `document.getElementById('something')` & subsequently this `formItem.value` because `formItem` would be `null`.